# How to query a child object within an aggregate root on demand?

Tags: domain-driven-design, aggregate

I'm learning DDD. For a practice, I'm trying to convert my own app to DDD aggregates.

What I understand so far on aggregate.

1. Aggregate defines transactional boundary
2. Design aggregate as small as possible
3. If there is no invariant to protect, I might not need an aggregate.
4. You need to load everything from an aggregate.

I have a simple example. When a user uploads an image and information on the image, my app creates products based on the image.

I have `Asset` aggregate and Asset has many `Product` entities (?)

```
class Asset
{
     public function newProduct(ProductType $productType) {
       // return a new Product object then save id internally
     }
}
```

When I add a new product to Asset, I save product id to Asset.
When I load Asset from its own repository, I get a problem. Since I have more than 30+ product types, it is not optimal to load all products together. Since a Product can't exist without an Asset and a Product id must be persisted to an Asset, I have a business logic to protect.

Do I really need to load all products when I load an Asset?

Can I have a method in Asset that accepts a DAO to retrieve a product on demand? or a domain service to retrieve a product from an Asset?

```
class Asset
{
    public function getProduct(ProductType $productType, aDAO $dao){

    }
}
```

Update: Asset can't have duplicate Product

Comment: What are the invariants that `Asset` protects?

Comment: @ConstantinGALBENU When a user adds a new Product to an Asset, Asset must have an ID of the Product. They can't be out of sync. That's all I can think of at this time.

Comment: This is not a real invariant. Why do `Asset` need the product ID?

Comment: @ConstantinGALBENU Asset acts as a parent class for Product. When I save a Product, it does not have all the information. Product objects retrieve data from its parent Asset. In other words, I must have a parent Asset in order to load Product. And..an Asset can't have duplicate Product. I figured that's an invariant.

Comment: I suppose you don't use `CQRS`, do you?

Comment: @ConstantinGALBENU Not at the moment.

Comment: What means a `duplicate Product`?

Comment: @ConstantinGALBENU Say I have CarToy product and TruckToy product. When I already have CarToy in Asset, Asset should not allow another CarToy to be added.

Comment: What means `When I save a Product`? I suppose that you modify some properties of the `Product`. Do `Asset` need to know about those properties that you modify in order to protect its invariants?

Comment: @ConstantinGALBENU I feel like I should update my question with a real example, but yes Asset needs to know when Product gets saved or updated. I guess I can do these saving/updating in a domain service instead. My main concern is duplication and loading a big object graph.

Comment: No. That does not fit into domain service responsibility. And I don't ever inject services (domain or application) into my aggregates so lazy loading is not an option.

Comment: @ConstantinGALBENU That's what I figured. I wanted to know how people handle this use case when they can't separate into another aggregate

Comment: The idea is that you must load the **entire** aggregate into memory before applying commands on it; the aggregate will have to have already loaded everything that it needs in order to protect its invariants. If you cut corners, like other do, you cheat. But firstly you need to see what are the **real aggregate boundaries**, that's why I asked you those questions, I needed to know your domain. From what I understand from your domain you need to load the entire aggregate as there is that `unique products invariant` that it needs to protect.

Comment: @ConstantinGALBENU Your last comment is true and that's how I understood from books and video tutorials. It's just that it's not really optimized for loading without CQRS. I think there is no real answer for my use case unless I use CQRS, which can be good or bad (another layer and one more server or db to maintain). Thank you for your insights.

Comment: There is another possibility, to split the `Asset` aggregate and extract a `Product` aggregate; the `Product` would have the fields that are not used by the `Asset` aggregate and a `Saga` would orchestrate the creation of `Product` aggregates. But you need to take into account that in this case the transactional boundary will not include the creation of the `Product` aggregate

Comment: @ConstantinGALBENU I either need to look into that or use CQRS. In real world though, it isn't really an issue even if I separate Product into another aggregate because I can create an unique product id with asset id. In that case, a DB will prevent duplication. I just thought that's somewhat cheating as it depends on database.

Comment: The main reason that you must load the entire aggregate into memory is concurrency. When you load from the repository an aggregate you should store the aggregate version and when persisting the changes you can compare that version with the version that exists in that moment in the DB (using a unique key constraint for example). In this way you detect the concurrent access and retry the command execution.

Answer (score 2):

In such situations, I'd ask myself if the business logic or model is right, not what I've implemented or what is best for software. One other thing that is important for Aggregate and DDD is ubiquitous language and implementation as business logic dictates, not what is best in software sense. So stuff like copy/paste in DDD is allowed (of course, this is a broad subject and should not be taken literary).

What puzzles me is the following sentence:

> When a user uploads an image and information on the image, my app creates products based on the image.

You say that product is created based on information that are entered with the image. So, a user enters an image and some information about it and based on these information you create products. As I understood, Asset is not based on products but on informations contained in images. Also, I don't really think that products don't share the same information or images. Therefore it's more of a many to many relation based on information and, probably, information can be interconnected with multiple images.

Like you said, aggregates define transactional boundary. In that case you can ask yourself a business logic question (irrelevant of how you've implemented it)

> If I delete an Asset, **MUST** all related products be deleted as well?
>   Are these products independent from other Entities?

If the answer is yes, ask yourself if the model is right, have you really implemented the model according to business logic. Go to the roots, the business logic defined by domain expert and business folks, not what is currently implemented.

Comment: The answer is Yes and that is exactly what business logic should be. Product depends on Asset, not the other way around.

Comment: @Moon - Can the products depend on other Assets as well? What is with these Information about the Images that you talk about? How do they fit in the entire picture?

Comment: Have you seen a website where they create a tshirt when you upload an image? It's basically the same idea, except that my app let you create more than t-shirt. There are over 30+ products. You can create 30+ products with a single image. That said, those 30+ products use the same title, description, and tags from Asset since they are based on the image in the Asset. An image uploader may disable/enable a product from an Asset.

Comment: If products are truly unique to an Asset, that they are transactionally related, that an Asset doesn't make sense without its Products, then, unfortunately, I can only say that you have to load them all. I don't know any other trick. Sorry :(...

Comment: // No need to be sorry. Thank you for your questions. I had to ask myself again to make sure.

Comment: What about lazy loading?